# how to set words pattern for input field

Tags: javascript

```
function wordCount(text) {
    totalCount = 0;
    words = text.split(' ')
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (word.length > 0) {
        totalCount++;
      }
    })
    
    return totalCount;
  }

  window.myFunction = function() {
   textarea = document.getElementById('txt');
   words = wordCount(textarea.value);
   if(words < 7 || words > 12) {
     alert('Wrong number of words');
   }
  }
```

i got this code here and it's working perfectly but instead of alert, i want it to display innerhtml error message but it's working, please i will appreciate any help.

Comment: So all you want is to display the error message on the page instead of an alert? Just add an element, select it, put the text in and toggle the `[hidden]` attribute depending on whether there's an error or something? It surprises me you got this far into coding and are now asking us to help solve the simpler thing of the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Wrong number of words"
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked, i'm a novice in the field i don't have money to register for a course and i need the knowledge so much. i so much appreciate.